# Is it permissible to raise our hands in salah?

Tags: salat, islamic-basis

I m a practicing Muslim and offen visit Saudi Arab for Umrah and Hajj and also vidits UAE for business, there I saw majority of peoples do Rfaidain(raising hands) in Namaz, When I come back and Offer salah in our local area masjid in India and do Rafaidain so people ask why you do so, please clarify Why we do RAFAIDAIN in Namaz?

Comment: I had asked the same question. Please check it in my avatar... U may get your answer

Comment: which salah you are referring to? Taraweeh, Jumuah, Tahajjud, Witr or fard?

Answer (score 1):

> Question: Yes in india we don't raise the hands. but the gulf people
>   do so. also in kerala were the malabari resides they also do so.
>
> Answer: Praise be to Allaah.
>
> The Prophet (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him) used to raise
>   his hands for takbeerat al-ihram (the takbeer at the beginning of the
>   prayer), sometimes whilst saying the takbeer, sometimes after it and
>   sometimes before. (al-Bukhaari and al-Nisaa’i)
>
> When he had finished reciting Qur’aan, he would pause for a moment
>   then raise his hands, say takbeer and do rukoo’. (Sifat Salaat al-Nabi
>   (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him), p. 128).
>
> He used to raise his hands when he stood up from rukoo’ (reported by
>   al-Bukhaari and Muslim), and this raising of the hands is mutawaatir
>   (reported by so many to so many that it is inconceivable that they
>   could all have agreed on a lie). It is the opinion of the majority of
>   scholars and of some of the Hanafis. (Sifat Salaat al-Nabi (peace and
>   blessings of Allaah be upon him) by al-Albaani, p. 136).
>
> The Prophet (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him) used to say
>   takbeer when he got up for the third rak’ah (reported by al-Bukhaari
>   and Muslim), and he would raise his hands sometimes when he said this
>   takbeer. (al-Bukhaari and Abu Dawood). (Sifat Salaat al-Nabi (peace
>   and blessings of Allaah be upon him), p. 177).
>
> Raising the hands in prayer was a well-known practice among the
>   companions of the Prophet (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him).
>   Imaam al-Bukhaari said: “Al-Hasan and Humayd ibn Hilaal said: ‘The
>   Companions of the Messenger of Allaah (peace and blessings of Allaah
>   be upon him) all used to raise their hands, without exception.” (Juz’
>   raf’ al-yadayn, p. 26, ma’a jila’ al-‘aynayn).
>
> Ibn al-Qayyim said: “Look at the practice at the time of the Prophet
>   (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him), and the Sahaabah after
>   him. They used to raise their hands in prayer when doing rukoo’, and
>   when standing up again. And in the time of the Sahaabah, if
>   ‘Abd-Allaah ibn ‘Umar saw someone not raising his hands in prayer, he
>   would throw a stone at him. [next phrase is unclear]. (I’laam
>   al-Muwaqqi’een, 2/376).
>
> So what is proven in the Sunnah with regard to raising the hands in
>   prayer is that they should be raised at four points in the prayer:
>   when pronouncing takbeerat al-ihraam, when doing rukoo’, when standing
>   up from rukoo’, and after standing up from the first tashahhud. And
>   Allaah knows best.

Source: [IslamQA](http://islamqa.info/en/1765)

Answer (score 0):

Doing Raff ul Yadain, meaning raising the hands, on the specific positions in Salah is a Sunnah of the Messenger SAW. However, there is a difference of opinion among the scholars on the issue whether it He SAW stopped doing it in his later years or not. Some are convinced that it continued till the last days while some claim that this act was abrogated. 
So do whatever you are convinced to be near the Sunnah. However, you should consult a scholar to avoid the confusion in order to favour one opinion.
Wa Allahu A'lam

Comment: Can edit your answer to provide a source for the part "Doing Raff ul Yadain, meaning raising the hands, on the specific positions in Salah is a Sunnah of the Messenger SAW. "